# Running a javascript function from .cs file?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a page file (aspx) and a (.cs file) where the user can input some rules to block or unblock lines of production. When the user finishes making any changes, he/she presses a buuton to save the data. First it makes a .txt file with all the rules that were made or changed.

After that I need to execute a .exe file (made in Python) that takes this information and makes another  text file by reading all the lines of production and all the orders (2 other files) to Block productions in certains lines. This is already done.

My problem is that I can't execute this .exe file. I have tried with this code in the .cs file

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "blockinglines", "BlockLine()", true);
```

And BlockLine function is this

```
<script>
    function BlockLine(){
        var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");               
        var bat = "\"C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\BlockLine\\Bin\\dist\\BLines.exe\" ";
        shell.Run(bat);
    }
</script>
```

But I can't run it. Is there any other solution to make this or an error I have made in the code??

Comment: How does this line of code attempt to execute an `.exe` file?  What is `BlockLine()` and what does it do?  It's really not clear at all what you're trying to accomplish here or how it needs to work.

Comment: Running javascript is one thing. Running an exe is another. You won't be able to do it. This is _by design._ It is an **important security feature** of every major web browser. You will not find any work arounds that allow you to run exe files from a web page. You need to go way back to the drawing board on this whole plan.

Comment: Joel Coehoom I had something that worked for handbreak video converter exe some time ago. But yeah, find a dll for your exe, OP and use it ...

Comment: @David I just edited to put the code for `BlockLine()`

Comment: Looking at this again: where to you expect this exe to execute? If it's on the server there may still be a glimmer of hope. But you should abandon any plan that expects a web site to cause an exe to run on the web browser computer.

Comment: @JoshuaCazares: And how exactly does this code fail?  Is the JavaScript executing at all?  Is the browser blocking the `ActiveXObject`?  Is there an error in the JavaScript console at all?  Does that file even *exist* on the client machine?

Comment: For this moment, and for testing the exe file generates a text file that says "Execution OK Hello world", but when I press the button it doesn't generate this file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "blockinglines", "BlockLine()", true);
```

With this:

```
Process.Start(@"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\BlockLine\Bin\dist\BLines.exe");
```

Then get rid of the `script` section entirely. You may also need to add a reference to `System.Diagnostics`.

And remember that this only works when you want your BLines program to run on the web server. If you want this to run on the browser, you're completely out of luck, and for good reason.

Comment: It showed me this error: `System.Exception: Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\BloqueoLinea\App_Data\BloqLines.txt' is denied.`

Comment: Think about what user account is running your web site, and make sure that account has access to this path.

Comment: I just gave full control to the IIS Users, and it generated the text file, thanks.